# Getting a "mutuelle" in France with EU health insurance

Tags: france, eu-citizens, health-insurance

I have my European (Czech in my case) governmental health insurance, which covers me during my stay in France as much as how local people are covered by "securité sociale", which is 60% of medical expenses.

To get more coverage, one has to get so-called "mutuelle". However, the insurance companies don't seem to provide "mutuelle only" for people who are covered by insurance from their home country.

So: Is there any way how can I get a "mutuelle" without having to pay the basic "securité sociale"? I'm a PhD student in both Czech Rep. and France if that makes any difference.

Comment: +1 as it's a valid and interesting question but note that a *mutuelle* often isn't necessarily such a good deal.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans I'm aware of that. It is one of the reasons why I haven't got one, despite being offered a reimbursement of the fee.

Comment: Have you tried contacting [CLEISS](http://www.cleiss.fr/)? As they are in charge of these things on the French side, they might know how to actually get a *mutuelle*.

Answer (score 1):

in France the mutuelle are indexed on the reimbursement made by the 'Sécurité Sociale' and technically are tightly linked to the use of the Carte Vitale.

I think it would be *possible* to get a mutuelle without having the Sécurité Sociale coverage, which would mean you'd have to pay the Sécurité Sociale part, you'll end up having a tremendous amount of paperwork to get reimbursements from your mutuelle, as well as from your Czech healthcare.

In the end, it may be more interesting for you to get a Czech *mutuelle* that works well with your Czech healthcare to have it both working smoothly with as little paperwork as needed.

HTH

Comment: -1 But that's the point, tohecz already has “securité sociale” coverage (presumably through an EHIC). There is probably no “mutuelle” in the Czech republic because the coverage there is different (even the structure of the healthcare system might be completely different). How is that supposed to work smoothly?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans That's quite true. However, I don't see a reason for -1, the answer well explains why it's complicated and says that it's better to search for another option. While it's not what I wanted to hear, it's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @tohecz Maybe it was a bit excessive but I feel the last advice “getting a Czech mutuelle” is completely off-base.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans It is. However, EU with it's almost 30 countries is so complicated that I understand this misunderstanding. Maybe it should be changed to something like: _"getting an extra healthcare in your home country if it's possible"_?

Comment: first of all, my last advice is a *maybe* because I do not know anything about Czech healthcare system. Secondly, what I'm stating in my answer is that I doubt it is possible to get a *mutuelle* without being covered by french healthcare because of the technicalities, and if it is, I'm pretty sure having each medical care being taken into account will be a massive headache of paperwork. Having to send the brown CERFA paper to the *Sécu*, having them forward it to the mutuelle, double declaring the act to the Czech healthcare etc. Not talking about the Kafka nightmare to actually get it to work

Comment: @zmo But the thing is that with an EHIC, expenses should already be declared and covered by the local system following the local rules in any case and *not* in your home country. Involving the Czech system is adding another layer of complexity.

Comment: so in the end, the answer to the OP's question is "**No you can't**"